# Windows Server - PHP files now need absolute paths for includes rather than relative paths

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server

For my sins I'm currently administering a Windows Server (standard edition) box for a company. They have several python and PHP scripts set up on this box that run as scheduled tasks. Sometime over the past few weeks these scripts stopped working. I've narrowed the culprit down to the way the scripts include files.

Currently files are included in the PHP script like so:

```
require 'example.php';
```

And this is what's breaking, changing these to:

```
require 'C:\scripts\example.php';
```

works fine... Something has changed on the box that means the require calls now need an absolute path rather than a relative path.

I've Googled for this but as with most MS products the docs and support are pretty sketchy at best.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);

include "$root/inc/include1.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP include_path settings, might be script path removed.